# Can I give a click option another name?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I use `click` like this:

```
import click

@click.command(name='foo')
@click.option('--bar', required=True)
def do_something(bar):
    print(bar)
```

So the name of the option and the name of the function parameter is the same. When it is not the same (e.g. when you want `--id` instead of `--bar`), I get:

```
TypeError: do_something() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

I don't want the parameter to be called `id` because that is a Python function. I don't want the CLI parameter to be called different, because it would be more cumbersome / less intuitive. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to add a non-option (doesn't start with `-`) argument in the `click.option` decorator. Click will use this as the name of the parameter to the function. This allows you to use Python keywords as option names.

Here is an example which uses `id_` inside the function:

```
import click

@click.command(name='foo')
@click.option('--id', 'id_', required=True)
def do_something(id_):
    print(id_)
```

There is an official example [here](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/master/docs/options.rst#basic-value-options) in the --from option.